# Iterate through XQuery sequence backward

Tags: xquery

Why does

```
  for $i in (0 to 3)
      return element color {"red"}
```

return

```
<color>red</color>
<color>red</color>
<color>red</color>
<color>red</color>
```

but reversing the iteration order

```
  for $i in (3 to 0)
      return element color {"red"}
```

returns nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the **[XPath 2.0 W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-RangeExpr)**:

> "*A range expression can be used to construct a sequence of
>   consecutive integers. Each of the operands of the to operator is
>   converted as though it was an argument of a function with the expected
>   parameter type xs:integer?. If either operand is an empty sequence, or
>   if the integer derived from the first operand is greater than the
>   integer derived from the second operand, the result of the range
>   expression is an empty sequence*"

**You can simply use something like this**:

```
for $i in (0 to 3)
 return color[4 - $i]
```

Comment: Fair enough (: Now I'm curious as to why 3 to 0 returns an empty range.

Comment: @RosePerrone: Because this is how the XPath 2.0 `to` operator is defined: "*A range expression can be used to construct a sequence of consecutive integers. Each of the operands of the to operator is converted as though it was an argument of a function with the expected parameter type xs:integer?. If either operand is an empty sequence, or if the integer derived from the first operand is greater than the integer derived from the second operand, the result of the range expression is an empty sequence*". See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-RangeExpr

Answer (score 1):

(0 to 3) returns a sequence of xs:integers 0 to 3

...but (3 to 0) returns the empty sequence!  (so its iterating zero times in your second example)

p.s.  xquery folk say "sequence" for "array"  :P

Comment: Thanks! How would you recommend I iterate through a sequence backward?

Comment: Wrap the for loop in a reverse(): reverse(  for $i in (0 to 3)
      return element color {"red"}
) .  Sorry I'm on my mobile, so formatting is kind of weird :-)

Comment: you can try fn:reverse in the zorba sandbox at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#6ZCO32IwRI3FjC0XOfKGICLhy2Q=